# Extending Groovy beans event handling to IEventNameListener interfaces

Tags: groovy, event-handling

According to [this mailing list thread](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Bean-style-event-handling-not-working-td346413.html), Groovy's event handling support doesn't work for those Eclipse event listener interfaces which are called `IEventNameListener` instead of `EventNameListener`. Is there some way to extend it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event handling support for beans is implemented according to the bean specification and doesn't have extension points for you to use. You will have to go the slightly longer way and do for example:

```
hl.addEventNameListener({...} as IEventNameListener)
```

with {...} being your Closure you want to handle the event with.